# new Shared Transition API not working for Imageview from One recycler view to another

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, android-transitions

I am trying to achieve the sharedElement to animate an imageView from one activity to another , but my problem is my imageView is inside recyclerView header so it doesn't animate.

So my question is, Is there a way for this to achieve?

I have seen many apps on PlayStore doing it

Code:
While starting 2nd activity

```
 String transitionName = getString(R.string.demo);

ActivityOptionsCompat transitionActivityOptions = ActivityOptionsCompat.makeSceneTransitionAnimation(mContext, v, transitionName);
startActivity(intent, transitionActivityOptions.toBundle());
```

and i have set:

```
ViewCompat.setTransitionName(icon, convertView.getContext().getString(R.string.demo));
```

to both my first activity grid and 2nd activity `recyclerView` Header

Comment: you'll need the activity which has the recycler view to get the shared element animation performed, which needs to be implemented in the OnClickListener in the onCreateViewHolder of the RecycleViewAdapter.

Comment: what do u mean activity of recyclerview?

Comment: The activity in which the recyclerview is a part.

Comment: It'll be easy to solve, if you can post the code

Comment: added the code please see it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your First acitivty imageview transition names have to be unique for the transition animation to work. In the Recycler grid  onBindView method you have to assign transition name for each imageview seperately using below code

```
holder.gridImageView.setTransitionName("gridImageTransition" + position);
```

Am adding the position to each grid image transition name to make it unique.

In ActivityOptionsCompat transitionActivityOptions = ActivityOptionsCompat.makeSceneTransitionAnimation(mContext, v, transitionName);

this transition name should be the same as the transition name you assign to Recycler view header in second activity using

```
    You will have to set the sharedTransition name for the imageView in your header after it has been inflated. Like below. Setting in xml wont work for the reason that it wont be immediately inflated.
```

Inside onBindViewHolder of your recycler adapter use

```
 holder.imageView.setTransitionName(transition);
```

Comment: ok let me try this ,and are this supported prelollipop throught prelollipop transition api

Comment: can u post a sample code which works with recyclerview header between activities ,I  don't know why it is not working for me, probably i am doing something wrong

Comment: Just show me your code and i will see what i can do

Comment: it is not working only exit transition is working not the enter one

Comment: Is your first layout a grid view?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108604/discussion-between-ankitagrawal-and-ragesh-ramesh).

Answer (score 0):

If your MainActivity has an `RecyclerView` adapter like this:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private SampleRecyclerViewAdapter adapter;    

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedBundle) {
        RecyclerView recycleView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycle_view);
        SampleRecyclerViewAdapter(this);
        recycleView.setAdapter(adapter);

    }
}
```

In Adapter Class,

```
public class public class SampleRecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {

    Context mContext;
    public SampleRecyclerViewAdapter(Context ctx) {
        this.mContext = ctx;
    }
    @Override
    public final RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        // Initiate ViewHolder and return it.
        return null;
    }    
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(VH viewHolder, int i) {
        viewHolder.view.setOnClickListener(
        new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick() {
                ActivityOptionsCompat transitionActivityOptions =
                ActivityOptionsCompat.makeSceneTransitionAnimation(this.mContext, viewHolder.view, transitionName);
                startActivity(intent, transitionActivityOptions.toBundle());
                ViewCompat.setTransitionName(icon, convertView.getContext().getString(R.string.demo));
            }
        }
        );
    }
}
```

In this code, `SharedElementTransition` code is implemented in adapter class.